# "Type '{ type: string; longitude: number; latitude: number; }' has no properties in common with type 'GeometryProperties'." error on angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, api, gis, arcgis

I followed every instruction on "https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources/tree/master/esm-samples/jsapi-angular-cli" and tried to add a point to the map using below snippet.

```
const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
sMap.add(graphicsLayer);

var point = {
            type: "point",  
            longitude: -71.2643,
            latitude: 42.0909
        };
        const simpleMarkerSymbol = {
            type: "simple-marker",
            color: [226, 119, 40],  
            outline: {
                color: [255, 255, 255], 
                width: 1
            }
        };

        
        const pointGraphic = new Graphic({
            geometry:point,
            symbol: simpleMarkerSymbol
        });

 graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);
```

But I am getting this
*Type '{ type: string; longitude: number; latitude: number; }' has no properties in common with type 'GeometryProperties'*
error. I don't know why.

Comment: I have no experience with Esri but am currently learning Leaflet and maps. Did a search and saw this format. "geometry" : {"x" : -118.15, "y" : 33.80}, does it work if you do something like this? What if you create a new Point() and set the type, lat, lng values or however it is that it is to be set?

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Point.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used new Point() to declare point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using
var point={}
I used
var point=new Point({});

code will be like,

```
import Point from '@arcgis/core/geometry/Point';

...

var point=new Point({
      longitude:-117.173138,
      latitude: 34.049599
    });

...
```